# Need explanation Classname name = new Classname2()

Tags: java, class

I need a fifth grade explanation on this example:

```
Car x = new Ford();
```

Why can a `Ford` be a `Car`?

Comment: You might have `Car` and `Ford` mixed up in your example.

Comment: Did you really mean child = parent and not vice versa?

Comment: `I need a fifth grade explanation on this`, also known as `I need to do this exercise for my homework, but I'm too lazy to think by myself`. We aren't going to make your test, you should think by yourself so you know how to do the same thing on your test. Happy coding :) -Charlie

Comment: It's called dynamic binding. You're creating an instance of the child class through the parent, effectively inheriting all properties and methods located in the parent class. Issue is your logic of a parent and child is backwards. Ford should be instantiated and Car should be made the parent and abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `x` is a `Ford` of type `Car`. This looks like an example of inheritance. `Car` is an abstract class containing things that all cars have, such as wheels, engine, body type, etc. `Ford` will implement these methods so they are specific to things that a `Ford` would have.

Simple example:

```
public abstract class Car {
    public boolean isCar() {
        return true;
    }
}

public class Ford extends Car {
    public boolean isFord() {
        return true;
    }
}

public class Audi extends Car {
   public boolean isAudi() {
        return true;
   }
}

System.out.println("Is Ford a car ? "+new Ford().isCar());
System.out.println("Is Audi a car ? "+new Audi().isCar());
System.out.println("Is Ford a ford ? "+new Ford().isFord());
System.out.println("Is Audi a ford ? "+new Audi().isFord());
```

The last line will probably give a NPE because the class `Audi` doesn't have a function `isFord()`.

Comment: Can you instantiate an abstract class? Can you assign a parent class instance to a subclass variable?

Comment: Then the explanation provided above is wrong. It will work if the question had been `Car x = new Ford()`.